# Visual Studio 2013 SSIS OLE DB Destination (Access via Connection Manager) SQL Command Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, ms-access-2010, bids

Afternoon Folks,

We are using Visual Studio 2013 and have an SSIS package that we are creating.  We have a simple Data Flow Task that essentially takes some data from SQL and Pushes through to an Access Database. It has three DFD flow items:

I have a OLE DB Source (obtains the SQL via a select statement) --> Data Conversion (Convert SQL Data Types to Access) --> OLE DB Destination (Access Database)

The steps selecting the SQL and converting it works fine.

The issue we have is the SQL command that we are using to update the Access 2010 database.

We have tried to run and create a simple UPDATE statement to update a couple of fields with hardcoded data, but this doesn't update. We have also tried creating a stored procedure and then executing this within the SQL Command line in the OLE Destination Editor.

We can see from posts on the net that we can create a procedure in access 2010 and use this.  We are also using Native OLE DB\Microsoft Office 12.0 access Database Engine OLE DB Provider.  This connection tests successfully.

We can write a SELECT statement within the SQL Command line and this does pull back data.  We just seem to have a problem with the UPDATE and or Create Procedure.  In turn we are unable to populate the Mappings.  the mappings display the destination box but no fields are displayed within here.

We have had a good look around on the internet but we are struggling to find a solution.

Here is a sample of the code in the form of the update statement we are trying to get working.

```
UPDATE ReferenceFields 
     INNER JOIN Addresses 
     ON ReferenceFields.ID = Addresses.ID
          SET ReferenceFields.Reference2 =CustomerName,
                 ReferenceFields.Reference3 = telephone           
WHERE Addresses.UPRN = 12345678910
```

If I Parse the query it is successful but when I select Mappings a warning is displayed....

> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [136]]: No column
>   information was returned by the SQL command

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff845861.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141044.aspx

[SSIS OLEDB destination with SQL command (Insert if not exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066301/ssis-oledb-destination-with-sql-command-insert-if-not-exists)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some time I have managed to answer this question myself.

I have added unique parameters to each field I need to update and used the @ char to set this.

```
UPDATE ReferenceFields 
     INNER JOIN Addresses 
     ON ReferenceFields.ID = Addresses.ID
          SET ReferenceFields.Reference2 = @CustomerName,
              ReferenceFields.Reference3 = @telephone
WHERE UPRN = @UPRN
```

This runs through the code and updates the MS Access database.